# Select min. three values of a record in another table with a JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have two tables:

Table 1: Article

```
Article_ID         Price Valid from         Price ID        
1                  12-Aug-2014              1
1                  30-Dec-2014              2
1                  10-Oct-2014              3
1                  15-Oct-2014              5
2                  13-Aug-2014              1
---(n no. of records for article 2)
3                  01-July-2014             4   
3                  02-July-2014             5   
---(n no. of records for article 3)
```

Here the unique key is Article_Id and Valid from date.

Meaning each article have different prices which are valid from certain dates. An article can not have different prices on the same valid from date.

Table 2: Price

```
Price ID            Price
1                   10
2                   200
3                   30
4                   400
5                   50
```

Required result:

I want for each article Minimum three Prices. For this I need a join, but I am not able to figure out how to restrict the no. of rows for each article Price to 3, and how to implement the min. criteria.

Final result should be:

```
Article_ID                     Min Price1      Min Price2    Min Price3
1                              10              30            50
2                              10    
3                              50              400
```

An article will have max. of three prices (in the final result), minimun could be 0. And three Prices it has are the smallest prices of the article from the table 2.

I get the idea that it has to do something with min. (Group by) and row no. (with a join on Table 2), but can anyone help me with it's implementation?

Regards
SJ

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: select a.article_id, min(p.price) from article a
left outer join price p on (p.price_id = a.price_id)
group by(a.article_id )
order by a.article_id;

Comment: Here the problem is that, I dont not know how to set the row Count to 3 (in case of a joint) and apart from that it is not considering the null price

Comment: @CodeNewbie : Actually this will also not help me, I have just realised that the required output is quite diff.(updated the ques.) Still trying to figure my way out.. let me know in case you have some idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirement remains for a pivot of 3 prices in a series, then using `ROW_NUMBER()` will enable giving these numbers 1, 2, 3 and from there is is a simple use of `case expressions` with a `group by`:

for 3 lowest prices:

```
SELECT
      a.article_id
    , MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.price_seq = 1 THEN p.price END) AS price_1
    , MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.price_seq = 2 THEN p.price END) AS price_2
    , MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.price_seq = 3 THEN p.price END) AS price_3
FROM (
            SELECT
                  article_id
                , price_valid_from
                , price_id
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY article_id
                                     ORDER BY p.price ASC) AS price_seq
            FROM article
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN price p
                              ON (a.price_id = p.price_id)
      ) a
GROUP BY
      a.article_id
ORDER BY
      a.article_id
```

for 3 most recent prices

```
SELECT
      a.article_id
    , MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.price_seq = 1 THEN p.price END) AS price_1
    , MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.price_seq = 2 THEN p.price END) AS price_2
    , MAX(CASE
            WHEN a.price_seq = 3 THEN p.price END) AS price_3
FROM (
            SELECT
                  article_id
                , price_valid_from
                , price_id
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY article_id
                                     ORDER BY price_valid_from DESC) AS price_seq
            FROM article
      ) a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN price p
                  ON (a.price_id = p.price_id)
GROUP BY
      (a.article_id)
ORDER BY
      a.article_id
```

<kbd>[Demo SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03668a/4)</kbd>

Comment: it's not working, in some cases it is returning null in all three Prices, in somw case it's returning only 1 smallest Price in Price2 col and in some cases it's picking the wrong values. PS: I have changed Price_valid_from to Price in row_number (as I need smallest 3 Prices and not latest 3 prices)

Comment: `I need smallest 3 Prices` OK, that will change it. I'll add a new variant

Comment: it will return NULLs if there is no price for the particular condition, can be amended to return 0 instead (change case expressions to include ELSE 0 )

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the min price of the articles in the article table limit will help you with getting the desired minimum value :

```
SELECT
        aa.article_id
      , (
        SELECT min(p.price)
        FROM article a
        LEFT JOIN price p ON (p.price_id = a.price_id)
        WHERE a.article_id = aa.article_id order by p.price limit 1,1
        ) AS minPrice1
    , (
        SELECT min(p.price)
        FROM article a
        LEFT JOIN price p ON (p.price_id = a.price_id)
        WHERE a.article_id = aa.article_id order by p.price limit 2,1
        ) AS minPrice2
    , (
        SELECT min(p.price)
        FROM article a
        LEFT JOIN price p ON (p.price_id = a.price_id)
        WHERE a.article_id = aa.article_id order by p.price limit 3,1
        ) AS minPrice3
FROM article aa;
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `limit` so this doesn't work for this situation. (12c does [introduce equivalent functionality though](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php)).

Comment: @parixit in the where clause which article_id you are referring to?

Comment: @Alex Poole Thanks..replaced Limit with Fetch statement