# Pivot first five results per id

Tags: oracle11g, pivot

I am working on creating a report that shows students and activities they participate in.

The request for the report needs one student per row.  The activities table has one activity per row.  I want to do a pivot, but can not find a way to do so.  There are no columns that I am aware of that I can pivot on and there are more than five activity types.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

example table:

```
aaron    football
aaron    soccer
aaron    baseball
aaron    tennis
aaron    basketball
aaron    volleyball
steve    basketball
steve    swimming
```

example output:

```
 aaron    football    soccer    baseball    tennis    basketball
 steve    basketball  swimming
```

edit:  using Oracle 11g

Comment: Sounds somewhat similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25377772/266304), but I'm not sure how you'd pick which five activites to choose, or how to order them - or doesn't it matter?

Comment: That's where I am having a problem.  The user I am making the report for asks for "the first five", so I assume the order doesn't matter.   and that might be just the question/ answer I was looking for.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to assign rank to the each sport and then apply [PIVOT](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0aec/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table myt(
player varchar2(10),
sport varchar(20)
);

insert into myt values('aaron',  'football');
insert into myt values('aaron',  'soccer');
insert into myt values('aaron',  'baseball');
insert into myt values('aaron',  'tennis');
insert into myt values('aaron',  'basketball');
insert into myt values('aaron',  'volleyball');
insert into myt values('steve',  'basketball');
insert into myt values('steve',  'swimming');

with x(player, sport, r) as (
  select player, sport, row_number() over (partition by player order by null) r
  from myt
  )
select * from x
pivot(max(sport) for r in (
                1 as first, 
                2 as second, 
                3 as third, 
                4 as fourth, 
                5 as fifth
                          )
      )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0aec/8/0)**:

```
| PLAYER |      FIRST |   SECOND |    THIRD | FOURTH |      FIFTH |
|--------|------------|----------|----------|--------|------------|
|  aaron |   football |   soccer | baseball | tennis | volleyball |
|  steve | basketball | swimming |   (null) | (null) |     (null) |
```